# Update two tables at once, using values from first table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case

So I need to Update table `scores` and use the updated value of column `won` to update the second table `tbl_users`. So far the code updates `scores`, but uses the old value of `won` for the second table update:

```
UPDATE scores a
left join tbl_users b on
    a.uid = b.userID
SET a.won = CASE  
WHEN a.nright = '0' THEN '0' 
WHEN a.nright = '1' THEN '25' 
WHEN a.nright = '2' THEN '50' 
WHEN a.nright = '3' THEN '100' 
WHEN a.nright = '4' THEN '200' 
WHEN a.nright = '5' THEN '400' 
WHEN a.nright = '6' THEN '700' 
WHEN a.nright = '7' THEN '1000' 
END,
b.pts=b.pts+a.won, 
b.pts_total=b.pts_total+a.won
WHERE a.uid=$user AND b.userID=$user
```

Comment: The actual order of the fields being updated may differ from the order specified in the sql statement, plus usually the entire existing record is fetched before the first change. You need to repeat the expression calculating the new won value in all the other expressions using won value.

Comment: Can you share the schema and sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is explicitly documented as correct:

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the
>   current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result
>   is that col1 and col2 have the same value. This behavior differs from
>   standard SQL.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

I assume that the issue is the multi-table update, where the `set` pulls the value from the earlier table.

You may be able to fix this using variables.  I am not 100% sure, but the following is worth a try:

```
UPDATE scores s JOIN
       tbl_users u 
       ON s.uid = .uuserID
    SET s.won = (@w := (CASE  WHEN s.nright = '0' THEN '0' 
                              WHEN s.nright = '1' THEN '25' 
                              WHEN s.nright = '2' THEN '50' 
                              WHEN s.nright = '3' THEN '100' 
                              WHEN s.nright = '4' THEN '200' 
                              WHEN s.nright = '5' THEN '400' 
                              WHEN s.nright = '6' THEN '700' 
                              WHEN s.nright = '7' THEN '1000' 
                       END)
                ),
       u.pts = u.pts + @w, 
       u.pts_total = u.pts_total + @w
    WHERE s.uid = $user ;
```

The documentation strongly suggests that the `set` clauses are processed in order for a single table.  Alas, it is not clear whether this is always true for multiple tables.

If not, you can use two updates.

Comment: It worked, I knew variables would do it, but I didn't know the right syntax. Thanks a lot.